# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error for type NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsobject

I'm new to this mac application development.

The app is working fine for some data and the app crashes for few entries.

```
-(void)presentClientsss
{
    [productVendorTextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[popUpVendor selectedItem] title]]];

    NSMenuItem *tempMenuItem = [popUpVendor selectedItem];
    NSString *selectedItemTitle = [tempMenuItem title];

    for (int k = 0; k < [appDelegate.vendorInfoArr count]; k++)
    {
        VendorInfo *tempCustomerInfoModel = [appDelegate.vendorInfoArr objectAtIndex:k];

        if ([tempCustomerInfoModel.vendorName isEqualToString:selectedItemTitle])
        {
            oldVendorIde = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", tempCustomerInfoModel.rowId];

            NSLog(@"Selected RowID = %@",oldVendorIde);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sending the `oldVendorIde`string to next method.

```
- (ItemModel *)itemNodelWithAttributes {
    isProductIdExist = NO;

    if ([senderInfo isEqualToString:@"nP"]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [appDelegate.itemsArr count]; i++) {
            ItemModel *tempIM = [appDelegate.itemsArr objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([tempIM.productId isEqualToString:[[productIdTextField stringValue] uppercaseString]]) {
                isProductIdExist = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ([senderInfo isEqualToString:@"eP"])  {
        for (int i = 0; i < [appDelegate.itemsArr count]; i++) {
            ItemModel *tempIM = [appDelegate.itemsArr objectAtIndex:i];
            if (tempIM.itemId == itemIdentity) {
                if ([tempIM.productId isEqualToString:[[productIdTextField stringValue] uppercaseString]]) {
                    isProductIdExist = NO;
                }
            }
            else if ([tempIM.productId isEqualToString:[[productIdTextField stringValue] uppercaseString]]) {
                isProductIdExist = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    int tempItemExists = [self saveProductImage:[[productIdTextField stringValue] uppercaseString]];

    NSLog(@"oldVendorIde =%@",oldVendorIde);
    ItemModel *iM = [[ItemModel alloc] initWithItemId:itemIdentity defaultItemMinimumValue:[productMinValueTextField floatValue] staticItemPrice:[productPriceTextField doubleValue] dynamicItemQuantity:[productCurrentStockTextField doubleValue] staticItemDescription:[productDescriptionTextField stringValue] prodId:[[productIdTextField stringValue] uppercaseString] itemVendor:oldVendorIde itemImgExists:tempItemExists stockAvailable:0 itemNotes:[notesTextField string] BarcodeDesc:[BarcodeDescTextView stringValue]];

    return iM;
}
```

In this method the same `oldVendorIde` is working fine for some data and some time it gets crashed at this point.

The `oldVendorIde` sometime doesnot get any value in `itemNodelWithAttributes` method and the app crashes at that point.

Can Sone help me to solve the issue.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The text from a `UITextField` is accessed through the `text` property (`[productIdTextField text]`), not through `stringValue`.

Comment: It would be an `NSTextField` not a `UITextField` but same deal.